# Populating One Select Box Based on Another When Selects are Arrays

Tags: php, jquery

I know how to populate one select box based on the option from another using jquery and ajax, but how do you do it when the select boxes are arrays?

By default there are 5 on the page, however I also am using .EnableMultiField() to add more lines as I need them... On any given week we add between 10 to 30 vehicles into our inventory.

Ajax:

```
$(".make").change(function() {
var id=$(this).val();
var dataString = 'id='+ id;

$.ajax ({
    type: "POST",
    url: "get_models.php",
    data: dataString,
    cache: false,
    success: function(html) {
        $(".model").html(html);
    } 
});

});
```

PHP:

```
            <ul>
            <li><label for="year[]">Year</label><select name="year[]"><option></option>'.$Year.'</select></li>
            <li><label for="year[]">Make</label><select name="make[]" class="make"><option></option>'.$Make.'</select></li>
            <li><label for="year[]">Model</label><select name="model[]" class="model" style="width: 120px"><option></option>'.$Model.'</select></li>
            <li><label for="trim[]">Trim</label><input type="text" size="10" name="trim[]" /></li>
            <li><label for="vin[]">VIN</label><input type="text" name="vin[]"size="20" maxlength="17" onkeyup="return Upper(event,this)" /></li>
            <li><label for="mileage[]">Mileage</label><input type="text" name="mileage[]" size="3" maxlength="6" /></li>
            <li><label for="color[]">Color</label><select name="color[]"><option></option>'.$Color.'</select></li>
            <li><label for="cost[]">Cost</label><input type="text" name="cost[]" size="6" maxlength="6" onchange="currency(this)" /></li>
            <li><label for="asking[]">Asking</label><input type="text" name="asking[]" size="6" maxlength="6" onchange="currency(this)" /></li>
        </ul>
```

Comment: `var dataString = \'id=\'+ id;`. is `\'` from real code or just some typo in the question?

Comment: I copied and pasted... The jquery code is wrapped in php, so I was escaping the quotes.

This code works, but only on the first "make" field

Comment: `This code works, but only on the first "make" field`. The markup has only one `make[]` field. Where are the others?

Comment: I only posted a snippet, the rest are there, just not posted. See: http://www.login.carcityofdanbury.com/New/01/add.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is that models you load via AJAX are set in all `.model`. You need to change your `$('.make').change(...)` to following

```
        $(".make").change(function () {
           var $this = $(this);
           var id = $(this).val();
           var dataString = 'id=' + id;

           $.ajax({
              type: "POST",
              url: "get_models.php",
              data: dataString,
              cache: false,
              success: function (html) {
                 $(".model", $this.closest('ul')).html(html);
              }
           });
        });
```

this will set new "models" only for `.model` present in changed `.make`'s `<ul>`

**Update**

to accommodate for dynamically added `.make`, replace

```
$(".make").change(function () {
```

with

```
$(document).on('change', 'ul .make', function () {
```

Comment: Actually, that ALMOST did it... It works correctly with the original 6 makes and models that are on the page, however if I add more (via the EnableMultiField() script) those new fields do not work.

Comment: You're good! That solved all of the rows, no matter how many I add

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion for the answer is that your first three `<label>`'s are mistakenly pointing at `year[]` instead of `year[]`, `make[]`, and `model[]`. Is that throwing off your stuff? It hits the first "make" field and throws up. Makes sense to me...

Good luck (:

Comment: No, the labels have nothing to do with it, they have since been removed from the page... Here is the page, so someone can see what I mean: http://www.login.carcityofdanbury.com/New/01/add.php